# Adding annotations when there are more than one function on the same plot

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I would like to add the annotations: "constant" with an arrow pointing to NSS1 in the plot, "short-term" with an arrow pointing to NSS2 in the plot and "hump" with an arrow pointing to NSS3.

I've seen the documentation and they show how to do this for a single equation but I'm stuck as to how to do it for multiple equations. Not even convinced I understand the single equation case fully!

```
lambda=5;
tau=0:30;

tau(1)=0.000001;

NSS1=1*ones(1,31);
NSS2=(1-exp(-tau/lambda))./(tau/lambda);
NSS3=((1-exp(-tau/lambda))./(tau/lambda)-exp(-tau/lambda));

plot(tau,NSS1,tau,NSS2,tau,NSS3);
title('The Nelson-Siegel Basis Functions')
xlabel('t = 0 to 30y')
ylabel('yield')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotations are unrelated to the data you are plotting, they can be anywhere on the graph, see the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/annotation.html) for more details. So in your case you can do something like:

```
a = annotation('textarrow', x1, y1,'String' , 'constant');
```

where `x1` and `y1`  are vectors with the coordinates of the arrow (begin and end points, so each vector has 2 elements). Use a similar approach for the other annotations.